# BigQuery - Get timezone offset from timezone name

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery

Is there any way in BigQuery to get the current UTC timezone offset from a timezone name? For example using the input:

```
`Australia/Victoria`
```

How could I currently return:

```
+10:00
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery STandard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Australia/Victoria' tz_string
)
SELECT  tz_string, DATETIME_DIFF(CURRENT_DATETIME(tz_string), CURRENT_DATETIME(), hour) tz_hours
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row tz_string           tz_hours
1   Australia/Victoria  10
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use the (at least, now) built in `FORMAT_TIMESTAMP()` function and the `%Ez` format element.

```
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Ez', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'Australia/Victoria');
```

Result:

```
+11:00
```